# Query too long in .NET 3.5 and SQL Compact 3.5

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

this is a rather pathetic problem:

In Visual Basic 2008 Express with SQL Server Compact 3.5 and the Usual DataSet / TableAdapters, My Query is too long:

Changing the names, it is a query like this:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table3.* 
FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.ID = Table2.T1ID 
    INNER JOIN Table3 
        ON Table2.T3ID = Table3.PK
```

Problem is, Table1 and Table3 have around 10 and 5 columns each, with rather descriptive names, and The Table adapter is insistent on writing all the columns out and therefore hacks off my command. (It won't take * 's, it always says it can't find the column Table1.* )

Is there a way around this?

Comment: do u need all the columns ? i rather prefer not to use * at all

Comment: sadly, yes. I need em all, even if it means my doom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an alias for the tables, will the table adapter take it?

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.* 
FROM Table1 t1
     INNER JOIN Table2 t2
         ON t1.ID = t2.T1ID
     INNER JOIN Table3
         ON t2.T3ID = t3.PK
```

Comment: I think it would still write out the Columns (t1.Column1, t1.Column2, ... etc ...)

Comment: Yes, but maybe it makes the query short enough.

Comment: good thinking, I'm upvoting even if this doesn't work, because it might for similar issues, and because there's a good idea behind it

Comment: since theres no further development on this question, and on the whole the answer is the best submitted, I'll accept it. FYI, I'm moving to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Put the query in a **stored procedure** and then just call it.
(It's also cleaner, more efficient, and helps encapsulate the logic within the database instead of your application just doing anything it likes)

Comment: Except stored procedures are not supported on SQL Server compact.